# Swift assigning a check mark to an item in an array and storing in NSdefaults

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So i have code like so

```
var item1Checked = true 
var item2Checked = false
var array = ["item 1","item 2"]
```

and I want the app to store wether or not they have been check marked or not in NSUserDefaults. The array is already set up to be stored in the NSUserDefaults How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `Array` of `Dictionaries`

```
let array = [["status" : "checked", "item" :item1], ["status" : "UnChecked", "item" :item2]]
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(array, forKey: "YourKey")
```